# scala function - how does it work?

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala/java and I'm trying to understand this code below which returns a list of files in a directory. [Function source](http://alvinalexander.com/source-code/scala/create-list-all-files-beneath-directory-scala)

1. It takes an argument called `dir` - is the type of `dir` a `File` or `File` object?
2. It returns an array of type `file`.
3. It calls the method `listFiles` on `dir`.
4. What does the last line do?

   ```
   def getRecursiveListOfFiles(dir: File): Array[File] = {
    val these = dir.listFiles
    these ++ these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(getRecursiveListOfFiles)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

This code does a breadth-first search, using recursion.

A `File` can either be a file, or a directory.

The code `dir.listFiles` list all files in directory. Remember that this will be a list of files and directories!

We can then break down the last line into 3 things. These could easily be separate lines.

1. `these.filter(_.isDirectory)` will return a list of directories that need searching in. It filters out the files.
2. `flatMap(getRecursiveListOfFiles)` takes this list of directories, and calls `getRecursiveListOfFiles` for every single directory. It then adds flattens these results into one list.
3. `++` adds together two arrays. We add `these` to the result of the recursive call.

`flatMap` is key here. Read up about it, and how it differs from the `map` function to fully understand what's going on.

Comment: This is the clearest explanation here. And it's worth adding that this method could be written tail recursive (`@tailrec`). I think making it so might be a good exercise for the original poster.

Answer (score 2):

In short:

```
 these ++ these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(getRecursiveListOfFiles)
```

is fundamentally:

```
 val allSubDirectories:Array[Files] = these.filter(_.isDirectory)
 allSubDirectories.flatMap(getRecursiveListOfFiles)
 //i.e. for each sub-directory, again find all files in sub-directory
 these ++ (files of all sub-directories)
 //ultimately add files of sub-directory to the actual list
```

Another alternative way to understand would be:

```
def getAllFiles(dir: File): List[File] = {
 val these = dir.listFiles.toList
 these ::: these.filter(_.isDirectory).map(x => getAllFiles(x)).flatten
}
```

Fundamentally same control flow, that for each sub-directory, you get a list of all the files and then to the same list, you add files of sub-directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to walk you through how I would think of this as someone trying to read a piece of unknown code.

It should be pretty clear by context that `File` can either be a regular file or directory. It doesn't contain the file contents, but represents any entry in the file system, and you can open the file with other library commands. For the purposes of this function, `File` is just something that happens to contain more `File`s in the case that it's a directory, and these can be accessed via the method `listFiles: List[Files]`. Presumably, it also provides other info, so that the original caller of `getRecursiveListOfFiles` could do something with the resulting list.

Also by context, `these` is pretty clearly the entries in the current directory.

The last line is the most subtle. But to break it down, it augments `these` with the `File`s found in those entries in `these` which happen to be directories.

To explain this step, the signature of `flatMap` on a `List[File]` can be thought of as `flatMap[B](f: File => List[B]): List[B]`, where `B` is a *type variable*. In this case, because the same function `getRecursiveListOfFiles`, which is of type `File => List[File]`, is being passed recursively, `B` is just `File`, so we can think of this particular call as `flatMap(f: File => List[File]): List[File]`.

Roughly speaking, `flatMap` applies a function `f` to each item in a container, where `f` is required to return the same type of container. The "flat" part is simply the fact that these individual containers get combined, instead of being nested, which is what `map` would do. This is what allows the function to recursively add all the files found in its subdirectories. Pretty slick.

Answer (score 0):

1. What's the distinction you're drawing? The type of `dir` is `File`.
2. An array of `File`s, yes.
3. It's probably implicitly converting `these` to a scala `List` or `Buffer`, which is the confusing part (e.g. it may import `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` - it's better to use `JavaConverters` which makes the conversions explicit calls to `.asScala` or `asJava`). You can find the definitions of `++`, `filter` and `flatMap` in [the scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List), which will hopefully be enough to understand what's happening.

(note: my 4. is coming out as a 3. because of markdown :()